# Select various cells according to different combinations of columns and rows

Tags: r

I have vector of index, that I'd like to filter by. In each column a different row will be selected. The output will be one vector of filtered values with the length of the number of columns. Bud without using the slow cycle. For example

```
set.seed(123)
(M <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5))

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818  1.7869131 -1.0678237
[2,] -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  0.4978505 -0.2179749
[3,]  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 -1.9666172 -1.0260044
[4,]  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827  0.7013559 -0.7288912
[5,]  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 -0.4727914 -0.6250393

indices <- c(2, 3, 1, 4, 4)
vect <- c()

for(i in 1:5) {
  vect <- c(vect, M[indices[i], i])
}
vect
[1] -0.2301775 -1.2650612  1.2240818  0.7013559 -0.7288912
```

I have larger data set and for cycle isn't therefore ideal. But I couldn't think of anything better, or find anything better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use a vectorized operation using `cbind`:  `M[cbind(indices, 1:ncol(M))]`

```
set.seed(123)
(M <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5))
indices <- c(2, 3, 1, 4, 4)

# vectorized
vect1 <- M[cbind(indices, 1:ncol(M))]

# loop
vect <- c()

for(i in 1:5) {
  vect <- c(vect, M[indíces[i], i])
}

# benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
mbm = microbenchmark(
vectorized =  M[cbind(indices, 1:ncol(M))],
loop = for(i in 1:5) {
  vect <- c(vect, M[indíces[i], i])
},
times=50
)
mbm

Unit: microseconds
       expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq    max neval cld
 vectorized    2.1    2.8    5.158    6.30    6.5   15.6    50  a 
       loop 2062.8 2089.2 2143.418 2114.55 2183.8 2391.0    50   b
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way of indexing the matrix entries

```
M[indices + (seq_len(ncol(M)) - 1) * nrow(M)]
```

Comment: thanks. There are certainly more options to avoid the cycle. I was completely out of ideas